# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js) Vue Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, babeljs

I downloaded a project from GitHub that me and my friend working on, however when I tried to run

```
npm run serve
```

I got this error

error in ./src/main.js

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main resolved in /home/haider/Desktop/L7G/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/package.json
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:524:9)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:661:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/haider/Desktop/L7G/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/haider/Desktop/L7G/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.109:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

content of main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import { ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate';

// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
// import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'


Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$form = false;
Vue.prototype.$sidebarShow = false;

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Add a rule.
extend('secret', {
  validate: value => value === 'example',
  message: 'This is not the magic word'
});

// Register it globally
Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);
// Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider);


new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

this is my tools that am using:
node v13.10.1
npm v6.14.2
@vue/cli 4.2.3
OS Manjaro Linux

This is what I tried to solve the problem:
reinstall Node modules
reinstall Node.js
using a different node.js version - v12.16.1
using different version of vue

Can anyone help??

Comment: something not right in `main.js`?

Comment: i just updated the question and added the content of main.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i solved the problem by deleting node_modules folder and package-lock.json from the project and then run

```
npm install
```

this solved the issue :)

Comment: The classic solutions never die 

Comment: I suspect this might be due to the node/npm upgrade. I've just seen this happen all of a sudden on a project I haven't touched in a couple of months. I then remembered that I've upgraded node from 12.x.x to 13.x.x recently.