# Rails/NPM - Module build failed [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED] for babel-loader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, babeljs, npm-install

I have a Rails app and something recently changed in such a way that the `rails server` will start but when I load a page I get an NPM related error in the browser console. I did not set up NPM/VueJS in this app so need some help getting it running locally...

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main resolved in /Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/package.json
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:524:9)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:661:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/debug.js:8:33)
    at Module._compile (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:19)
    at require (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at requireModule (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:165:12)
    at loadPreset (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:83:17)
    at createDescriptor (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at /Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
    at mergeChainOpts (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:320:26)
    at /Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:283:7
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at buildRootChain (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-chain.js:90:27)
    at buildRootChain.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig (/Users/meltemi/rails/myapp/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/partial.js:95:62)
    at loadPrivatePartialConfig.next (<anonymous>)
```

This is similar to an issue reported recently in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766096/module-build-failed-from-node-modules-babel-loader-lib-index-js-vue-js) but in that case NPM wasn't embedded in a Rails app. Regardless **I tried their solution** by removing `node_modules` (there is no `package-lock.json`) and running `npm install` but that led to more errors in the shell:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated postcss-cssnext@3.1.0: 'postcss-cssnext' has been deprecated in favor of 'postcss-preset-env'. Read more at https://moox.io/blog/deprecating-cssnext/
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.4: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git checkout ^2.4.0
npm ERR! error: pathspec '^2.4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
npm ERR!
```

This app is working in production so I'm not interested in updating outdated libraries at the moment. I'm not an NPM/JS guru so would appreciate any advice no matter how rudimentary this probably is.  Thanks!

**Edit:** Results of `yarn install --check-files` as per request

```
$ yarn install --check-files
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
[4/5]   Linking dependencies...
[5/5]   Building fresh packages...
$ node -e "try { require('fs').symlinkSync('../../node_modules/@bower_components', 'vendor/assets/components', 'junction') } catch (e) { }"
✨  Done in 10.22s.
```

Comment: Are you using Linux or Mac?

Comment: MacOS (10.15.4)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using yarn on your project? If so try:

```
yarn install --check-files
```

And please post the result of your terminal.

Comment: Results of `yarn install --check-files` above.  Also tried removing the `node_modules` folder and running `yarn install` again…to no avail.

Comment: Removing node_modules is not sufficient, also need to remove yarn.lock

Answer (score 0):

this my case , just remove node_modules and package-lock.json and run `npm install`so `npm run build` working correctly.[show here for this answer](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11216)